# Validate won't submit form with ajax check

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate, form-submit

I'm using the [jQuery Validate plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) to validate an email field in my form by making an ajax request to make sure that the email is not already taken by another user. I do so by adding a rule like this:

```
//make sure email field is on form before adding rule
if ($(".unique_email").is("*")) {
    //remote validation
    $(".unique_email").rules("add", {
        remote: "http://test.nethop.com/test.cgi",
        messages: {
            remote: "This email is already in use"
        }
    });
}
```

However, whenever I hit 'submit' on the form, it will first do an ajax request to make sure the email isn't taken, and then it will not submit even if the email validates as okay. You have to hit submit one more time and then it will submit. Does anyone know why this is?

I've set up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/42TK4/4/) demonstrating the problem. If you use chrome developer tools or firebug, you can see the ajax request being made, returning `true`, and still not submitting.

The HTML

```
<form id="listing" method="post">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label for="username">Email *</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" autocomplete="off"
            class="email required unique_email" value="test@test.com" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn" value="Save"
            />
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

The full script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var validator = $("form").validate({
        onkeyup: false,
        onblur: true,
    });

    if ($(".unique_email").is("*")) {
        //remote validation
        $(".unique_email").rules("add", {
            remote: "http://test.nethop.com/test.cgi",
            messages: {
                remote: "This email is already in use"
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Though a duplicate still +1 for good question and also added the full code from the fiddle for completeness in case of fiddle going down/dead or link-rot. That way this question is useful to users with similar issues in the future. Specially seeing that the HTML names/ids were part of the problem/solution.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl: Agreed, I kind of wish I could rescind my vote, this is a much more concise question that better demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker: I also voted for duplicate, purely cause it was, regardless of the quality of the question. Hence the +1 as it is a good question addressing a quite common issue. Though I like this question better as it is of better quality it still is sadly a duplicate. Duplicate question aren't removed though. As far as I know there merely prevent more answers from being posted, still making this question a good quality question to come across from google

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, this one is kind of weird so bear with me.

The fact that you have an `input` with name/id `submit` is causing the problem. I *think* this is because under the hood, jQuery validate is calling `form.submit`. In your case, `form.submit` is a form element and so this does nothing.

If you rename the `submit` button, everything works fine.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/42TK4/7/

Comment: wow, great solution. How'd you track that down?

Comment: @srchulo: Thanks--I kind of got lucky... I noticed the submit button and know that form elements can be accessed by name.

Comment: +1 Very nice. No need for a `submit` binding work-around. Never knew jQuery validate works this way.

Comment: Yup, I've been bit by this one before.